# Can I set up Nautilus to use transparent background?

Tags: nautilus, transparency

I think it'd be nice if Nautilus windows could have semi-transparent backgrounds (same as Gnome terminal can) for files and places lists. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Compiz settings manager (you need to install "compizconfig-settings-manager" package, and then run the "CompizConfig manager" from the "System->Preferences" menu).

Under the "Accessibility" item, you have "opacity, luminosity" option. There you can define the opacity (and then, transparency) of your windows, and you can set it based on the window title or type...
 If you create a new item here, you can type "class=Nautilus" and select the transparency you want. Then all Nautilus windows will be transparent.

Comment: On my graphics card (Intel 82852/855GM) I can't use Compiz without a good joint ;-) But Metacity's composition works fine, and terminal manages with transparency even without compozitor's help. And I don't want panels to go transparent - only file/places lists.

Comment: Seen... Sorry, I don't see the solution then :-(

Answer (score 0):

The desktop window, created by Nautilus and most other DE, also have `type` property set to `Desktop`. In ccsm it should look like `type=Desktop`.